# "The given path's format is not supported" on form load,

Tags: vb.net

I am making an application for school. It has four buttons and one of which opens a logs window. It gets all of the text files in each folder and displays them in a DataGridView. All of this is on a mapped network drive on a domain controller. When the form with the table loads it throws "The given path's format is not supported." This is my code:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Date/Time")
        dt.Columns.Add("Username")
        dt.Columns.Add("Room")
        For Each dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("T:\(IncidentReport)\logs")
            Dim infoa As New IO.DirectoryInfo("T:\(IncidentReport)\logs\" + dir)
            Dim infob As IO.FileInfo() = infoa.GetFiles("*.txt")
            Dim infoc As IO.FileInfo
            For Each infoc In infob
                Dim log() As String
                log = File.ReadAllLines("T:\(IncidentReport)\logs\" + dir + "\" + infoc.Name)
                Dim row = dt.NewRow()
                row(0) = log(0)
                row(1) = log(2)
                row(2) = log(1)
                dt.Rows.Add(row)
            Next
        Next
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any ideas anyone? Bit stuck here...

(I've tried changing them to my "user area" on my domain user which I have 100% control on and there was no difference)

Comment: The program does not recognize your T: drive.  Try putting the full UNC path in.

Comment: I could try but the school's part of a managed service from a different place so I don't know if I could get my hands on it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Directory.GetDirectories()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetDirectories_System_String_) function returns FULL PATH strings:

> Returns String[] An array of the full names (including paths) of
>   subdirectories in the specified path, or an empty array if no
>   directories are found.

So in your next line of code:

```
Dim infoa As New IO.DirectoryInfo("T:\(IncidentReport)\logs\" + dir)
```

You're concatenating a full path with another full path, which obviously won't work.

I'd approach it more like below, to side step these kinds of issues.  This re-work creates a DirectoryInfo from your main folder, then retrieves the subfolders with [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.8).  From there, we iterate over FileInfo instances via [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_DirectoryInfo_GetFiles_System_String_).  Lastly, we get the full path filename with [FileInfo.FullName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname?view=netframework-4.8):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Date/Time")
dt.Columns.Add("Username")
dt.Columns.Add("Room")

Try
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo("T:\(IncidentReport)\logs")
    For Each subFolder As DirectoryInfo In folder.GetDirectories
        For Each FI As FileInfo In subFolder.GetFiles("*.txt")
            Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(FI.FullName)
            If lines.Length >= 3 Then
                dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {lines(0), lines(1), lines(2)})
            End If
        Next
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Reading Files")
End Try

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this soon :)

Answer (score 0):

We can flatten this code considerably. Also, never pass up the chance to move code out of an the immediate event handler, or to save memory by enumerating items rather than loading them all in an array:

```vb
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.DataSource = LoadLogFiles("T:\(IncidentReport)\logs")
End Sub

Public Function LoadLogFiles(ByVal basePath As String) As DataTable
    Dim result As new DataTable()
    result.Columns.Add("Date/Time")
    result.Columns.Add("Username")
    result.Columns.Add("Room")

    Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(basePath)

    For Each fileInfo In dir.EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim row = result.NewRow()
        Dim column As Integer = 0  

        'This is better if a log could have many lines and you only care about the first three.
        'If the files only have exactly three lines, just read to an array like you were.    
        For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(fileInfo.Name).Take(3)
           row(column) = line
           column += 1
        Next

        result.Rows.Add(row)
    Next
    Return result
End Sub
```